# Select from 2 tables with count()

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

`Dictionary` table:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | Italian |

`Word` table references `DictionaryID`:

| ID | DictionaryId | Word |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 2 | C |

I want to achieve a single query with a left join between `Dictionary` and `Word` table and as result, all fields from `Dictionary` table, and only the count of rows from the `Word` table in a field called `WordNumber` as in:

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Collation("NOCASE")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public long WordNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have a function that returns the list of dictionaries based on a text search and this is working:

```
public async Task<List<Dictionary>> GetDictionariesForSearchAsync(string search)
{
    await Init();
    return await Database.Table<Dictionary>()
        .Where(w => w.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

For each `Dictionary` I read the number of words:

```
public async Task<long> GetRecordNumberForDictionary(long id)
{
    long num = await Database.Table<Word>().Where(i => i.DictionaryId == id).CountAsync();
    return num;
}
```

I'm duplicating queries (a single query is more efficient). I can't find a function like `GroupBy` to group and count `Word`.

[William's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76879132/4157124) gets me this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you tried to use the 'GroupJoin' method which allows you to perform a left join and group the results based on a specific key.

In your case, you want to group the 'Words' table by 'DictionaryId' and count the number of words for each group.

```
public async Task<List<Dictionary>> GetDictionariesForSearchAsync(string search)
{
    await Init();

    var dictionaries = await (
        from dict in Database.Table<Dictionary>()
        where dict.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        join wordGroup in
            (
                from word in Database.Table<Word>()
                group word by word.DictionaryId into wordGroup
                select new { DictionaryId = wordGroup.Key, WordCount = wordGroup.Count() }
            )
        on dict.ID equals wordGroup.DictionaryId into wordCounts
        from wordCount in wordCounts.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new Dictionary
        {
            ID = dict.ID,
            Name = dict.Name,
            WordNumber = (wordCount != null) ? wordCount.WordCount : 0
        }
    ).ToListAsync();

    return dictionaries;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Unfortunately, it is not working. See my update